# Are there examples of marking coins to know how they are used?

Tags: money, korea

I've seen in a video game (Empire: Dawn of the modern world) that the king of Korea was putting mark on some coins to have a better idea of how this money is spent (in this story, it is used to discover a traitor).

Is it true?

Or does it have similarity (true) with the real history (anywhere else in the world)?

I'm searching an "old" example, let say before 1600 AD.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: ? I don't understand how this works? Who marked the coins? How did they count the marked coins?  What information did they derive from counting marked coins? Bills have serial numbers, and the serial numbers can be used to trace money - I have no idea how often that is done, but it is a common fictional trope.   At least in the US, all large electronic transactions must be reported. Not entirely sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Dye packets in bank thefts would also seem relevant; they mark money that participates in illegal transactions.

Comment: I was thinking about more ancient example. But yes serial numbers could be considered as a mark, if it has been done intentionally to trace money (as far as I know it's not the case for bills); I will edit my question.

Comment: Coins *circulate* - that in fact is their value and purpose. After a month or two, and a few dozen transactions, long before the coins could ever return to an official, the coins would be a mangled mas of metal with neither the minting nor any of the transaction markings being legible.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Could you justify your assertion with some reference?

Comment: Within the past couple hundred years, silver coins were "chopped" with marks to indicate that their coin was indeed completely silver and not plated; they were also used to test the silver content, These marks were punched into the coins by private individuals and was primarily an Asian practice. See https://forums.collectors.com/discussion/906185/chop-marks-and-test-cuts if you want more info and photos.

Comment: @fedor: Google "*hardness of precious metals*" The *biting* of coins to test their purity works precisely because base metals are much harder than precious metals are.

Comment: @Jurp: (1) That's a great way to slowly collect chips of silver worth ***real money***. (2) That's  ***not*** a transaction stamping indicating usage. In fact it's very very different.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens. The trefoil drilled chops are about stealing a bit of silver; the other chops are about verifying that the coin is not plated, as stated in the linked thread. Neither is, indeed, transactional. As you noted, marking coins by type of transaction is untenable, as I believe some of the photos in the thread showed.

Comment: Reminds me of the practice of paying people in $2 notes to demonstrate the impact of certain activities within a local economy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_two-dollar_bill  and the issuing of 'trade tokens' by merchants https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_coin

Comment: How would that work? A traitor is paid by the enemy, so you should have to give the marked coins to the enemy and ensure that the enemy uses those (and no other coins or goods) to pay the traitor and then known when the exchange has happened. If you have so much information you probably already know who is the traitor. What if the enemy uses the money to legally buy something from a loyal officer? This seems like an adaptation of the popular TV trope that ransom money is paid with notes correlative serial numbers to identify them, and nothing of historical significance.

Comment: I _think_ we're converging on "No, there are no examples that match the filter you've set."